# Polygon coordinates are wrong after shapefile import

Tags: geometry, sql-server, boundaries

I have shapefile I have imported, but the polygon coordinates are wrong. Was the shapefile exported incorrectly or is there something I'm missing.

Point 30.8843 -29.9688 should fall in the boundary.

[image: Does not intersect although it should]

Comment: While not strictly required, most shapefile generators will populate a `.prj` spatial reference file. Please [Edit] the question include the contents of the projection file in the Question body.

Answer (score 3):

The coordinates of your polygon are not in lat-long degrees, so the first task is to identify what projection and coordinate system this is. For example, the mid point of the polygon is approximately -3288,600N and 8,300E.